# Can Turing Machines decide on computability?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, real-numbers

Can a Turing Machine decide whether an arbitrary real number is computable or not? Does this even follow from the solution of the Halting problem? If not, who proved it?

Comment: Should "Turing machine" be replaced with "[Blum-Shub-Smale Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum–Shub–Smale_machine)"? $\;$

Comment: When do you consider a real number to be computable?

Answer (score 8):

A real number cannot be input into a Turing machine, since it is an infinite object. There are various models for providing a Turing machine with oracle access to real numbers, but these are by definition computable.

You could imagine a Turing machine given a ZFC definition of a real number, and in that case it's undecidable. For example, given a Turing machine $T$, you could define a number $x$ as follows: if $T$ doesn't halt in $n$ steps then the $n$th bit of $x$ is zero. Otherwise, it is the $n$th bit of Chaitin's constant. So $x$ is computable if and only if $T$ never halts.